# vue js mounted firebase asynchronous call does not update data

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, vue.js

I know what the problem is, but I cant find solution on internet for my case. So I call data from firebase with this line:

> this.$store.dispatch('getConsumptionFromFirebase')

but my mounted() function on Doughnut.vue file is being called before I get data from firebase, because when I go to other component and return here, data will be rendered because it was previously loaded. How can I fix this issue, I need data to be rendered instantly. Here is the code:

My mainComponent.vue file:

```
<Doughnut class="chartSize" :labels="labelsDoughnut" :data="dataDoughnut" :colors="backgroundColorDoughnut"></Doughnut>


<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
  import Doughnut from '@/components/Graphs/Doughnuts'
  export default {
    components: {
      Doughnut
    },
    data () {
      return {
        labelsDoughnut: [ 'Air Conditioning & Heating', 'Cleaning Appliances' ],
        backgroundColorDoughnut: [ '#41B883', '#E46651' ]
      }
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        airConditioningHeatingMonthlyConsumption: 'airConditioningHeatingMonthlyConsumption',
        cleaningAppliancesMonthlyConsumption: 'cleaningAppliancesMonthlyConsumption'
      }),
      dataDoughnut: function () {
        return [ this.airConditioningHeatingMonthlyConsumption, this.cleaningAppliancesMonthlyConsumption ]
      }
    },
    created () {
      this.$store.dispatch('getConsumptionFromFirebase')
    }
  }
</script>
```

My Doughnut.vue file:

```
<script>
  import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs'
  export default {
    props: ['labels', 'data', 'colors'],
    extends: Doughnut,
    data () {
      return {
        chartOptions: {
          legend: {
            position: 'top'
          }
        },
        dataCollection: {
          labels: this.labels,
          datasets: [ { data: this.data, backgroundColor: this.colors } ]
        } 
      }
    }, 
    mounted () {
      this.renderChart(this.dataCollection, this.chartOptions)
    }
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Could you add the code of your store? At least for getConsumptionFromFirebase

Comment: What do you mean "instantly"? Do you want to hide the component until it's loaded, or does the data not show up once it's loaded?

Comment: Are you using Vuex, if not what is $store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you render your component manually by calling `this.renderChart(this.dataCollection, this.chartOptions)`

So maybe is a good idea to use computed instead of data, and watch:

```
<script>
  import { Doughnut } from 'vue-chartjs'
  export default {
    props: ['labels', 'data', 'colors'],
    extends: Doughnut,
    computed: {
        chartOptions () {
          return {
            legend: {
              position: 'top'
            }
          }
        },
        dataCollection () {
          return {
            labels: this.labels,
            datasets: [ { data: this.data, backgroundColor: this.colors } ]
          } 
        }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.renderChart(this.dataCollection, this.chartOptions)
    },
    watch: {
      chartOptions: function () {
        this.renderChart(this.dataCollection, this.chartOptions)
      },
      dataCollection: function () {
        this.renderChart(this.dataCollection, this.chartOptions)
      }
    }
  } 
</script>
```